# How do i handle the russian language?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2

Problem: Text get broken in MySQL.

[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7VT9.png)

A. Text is sent over webservice as below

```
$text = 'как дела';

    $data = array( 
        'text' => $text, 
        'client' => 'abcd');
    
    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'content' => http_build_query($data)
        )
    );
    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
    $result = file_get_contents(sms_url, false, $context);
    if ($result === FALSE) { 
    }
    return $result;
```

B. Controller receives the text and need to insert to MySQL:

```
$text = utf8_decode($_POST['text']);
$data = array(
              
              'text' => $text,

          );
          $insert->values($data);
          $selectString = $sql->getSqlStringForSqlObject($insert);
          $adapter->query($selectString, Adapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE);
```

MySQL column is  utf8_general_ci (other language english no problem).

EDIT:

Before inserting to MySQL the data is showing in Russian correctly. But after insert into the MySQL the column shows like this: `Ð¢ÐµÑ€Ð¼Ñ–Ð½Ð¾Ð²Ð¸Ð¹`

Comment: I'm not a php guy, but if it were me, I'd start with identifying when/where in the process the characters are corrupted. Start by echoing the value of `$text`  on both sides . Determine a) what value is actually submitted and b) what value is actually received... If the characters are already corrupted, it's likely not a database issue.

Comment: Here it is corrupted `$context  = stream_context_create($options);
    $result = file_get_contents(sms_url, false, $context);`

Comment: for save russian text in DB need special setting on DB. Like " COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci' " on create DB

Answer (score 2):

The call to `utf8_decode` is unessessary and is corrupting your text. It does not handle Russian, and it shouldn't be needed at all.

`utf8_decode` per the manual "Converts a string with ISO-8859-1 characters encoded with UTF-8 to single-byte ISO-8859-1"

Russian characters are not contained in ISO-8859-1. If you run

```php
echo utf8_decode('как дела');
```

outputs

```
??? ????
```

See: https://3v4l.org/TsMU4

Comment: I removed `utf8_decode` but still same. adding `???????` instead of Russian

Comment: Before inserting to MySQL the data is showing in Russian. But after insert the column shows `Ð¢ÐµÑ€Ð¼Ñ–Ð½Ð¾Ð²Ð¸Ð¹`

Comment: What encoding is your database connection set to?

Answer (score 0):

Use `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` as your column collation.

Comment: Russian should fit fine into 3 byte unicode.